# Числа Фибоначчи, программа

Tags: c

"Вычислить и вывести номер первого элемента последовательности Фибоначчи, которое превышает 1000."
Нужна помощь в написании программы для данного задания, т.к после начала работы моей программы, она ничего не выдает. Надо сделать именно через 2 переменные

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    while (a + b < 1000)
    {
        a = a + b;
        b = a - b;
        a = a - b;
    }
    printf("%d", a + b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ну пройдись на бумажке по своей программе пару циклов и посмотри, чему равны а и b каждый раз... Ну или хотя бы вставь printf("%d", a + b); внутрь цикла, сразу увидишь

Comment: @Эникейщик ну у меня вроде как просто бесконечный цикл, я просто не могу понять, что мне надо исправить

Comment: Вероятно, имеет смысл посмотреть на вычисления, которые происходят в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что вы не можете отловить данный момент, но ваш код будет работать, как только вы удалите данную строчку кода
`a = a - b;`
по факту, вы по кругу отнимаете единицу и снова ее прибавляете.
Итоговый вариант получается так

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    while (a + b < 1000)
    {
        a = a + b;
        b = a - b;
    }
    printf("%d", a + b);

    return 0;
}
```

> Вывод: 1597

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо. Просто через 3 переменных я сделал, а с двумя, я не знаю почему, вообще начал тупить